# Grouping siblings according to a starting element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

The input xml contains multiple repeated records of different  shipments.
Record 1 ,2 and 3 belongs to one shipment and again Record 1,2 and 3 are belongs to another shipment.
The output should be like output xml. Each shipment get transformed to a `Root-Element`.

input:

```
 <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <Root-Element>

          <RECORD1>
             <C2>500000000222725718846C </C2>
             <C3>3014 </C3>
             <C4> DELVRY02  </C4>
          </RECORD1>
          <RECORD2>
             <C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
             <C3>000010000000200</C3>
             <C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
           </RECORD2>
          <RECORD3>
             <C2> 50000000022272</C2>
             <C3>5718800000</C3>
             <C4>200000103002</C4>
          </RECORD3>


         <RECORD1>
             <C2>5000000002227ABCD </C2>
             <C3>3014 </C3>
             <C4> DELVRY02  </C4>
          </RECORD1>
          <RECORD2>
             <C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
             <C3>000010000000200</C3>
             <C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
           </RECORD2>
          <RECORD3>
             <C2> 50000000022272</C2>
             <C3>5718800000</C3>
             <C4>200000103002</C4>
          </RECORD3>

    </Root-Element>
```

output:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root-Element>
<shipment>
<RECORD1>
<C2>500000000222725718846C </C2>
<C3>3014 </C3>
<C4> DELVRY02 </C4>
</RECORD1>
<RECORD2>
<C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
<C3>000010000000200</C3>
<C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
</RECORD2>
<RECORD3>
<C2> 50000000022272</C2>
<C3>5718800000</C3>
<C4>200000103002</C4>
</RECORD3>
</shipment>
<shipment>
<RECORD1>
<C2>5000000002227ABCD </C2>
<C3>3014 </C3>
<C4> DELVRY02 </C4>
</RECORD1>
<RECORD2>
<C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
<C3>000010000000200</C3>
<C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
</RECORD2>
<RECORD3>
<C2> 50000000022272</C2>
<C3>5718800000</C3>
<C4>200000103002</C4>
</RECORD3>
</shipment>
</Root-Element>
```

I tried this below xslt, but it is giving one issue.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="items" match="Root-Element/*"
           use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::RECORD1[1])"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Root-Element">
    <Root-Element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD1"/>
    </Root-Element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="RECORD1">
    <shipment>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('items', generate-id())"/>
    </shipment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output getting with the above xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root-Element>
<shipment>
<RECORD1>
<C2>500000000222725718846C </C2>
<C3>3014 </C3>
<C4> DELVRY02 </C4>
</RECORD1>
<RECORD2>
<C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
<C3>000010000000200</C3>
<C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
</RECORD2>
<RECORD3>
<C2> 50000000022272</C2>
<C3>5718800000</C3>
<C4>200000103002</C4>
</RECORD3>
<RECORD1><!-- it should not come....This is the issue -->
<C2>5000000002227ABCD </C2> 
<C3>3014 </C3>
<C4> DELVRY02 </C4>
</RECORD1>
</shipment>
<shipment>
<RECORD1>
<C2>5000000002227ABCD </C2>
<C3>3014 </C3>
<C4> DELVRY02 </C4>
</RECORD1>
<RECORD2>
<C2> 50000000022272571880</C2>
<C3>000010000000200</C3>
<C4>9659666341109001 </C4>
</RECORD2>
<RECORD3>
<C2> 50000000022272</C2>
<C3>5718800000</C3>
<C4>200000103002</C4>
</RECORD3>
</shipment>
</Root-Element>
```

Comment: I've edited your title and some of your text because the way it was formulated your question looked at first glance like it was asking how to create something which is not valid XML. (The 2 close votes present right now are probably due to this.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="items" match="Root-Element/*[name() != 'RECORD1']"
           use="preceding-sibling::RECORD1[1]"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Root-Element">
    <Root-Element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD1"/>
    </Root-Element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="RECORD1">
    <shipment>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('items', .)"/>
    </shipment>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tested it with xsltproc and saxon. `generate-id` was not necessary for the keys. One major issue with the code you had was that the keys included `RECORD1` in the group of elements that had the same key.  Since they are grouped by looking at the preceding RECORD1 element, then any given RECORD1 element would end up grouped with the group that precedes it. The solution was to exclude it.

Comment: the code is not working for me,because I think i am using oracle xslt processer ,not an saxon.

Comment: Did you try reintroducing ``generate-id``? Neither xsltproc nor saxon need it but maybe the Oracle processor somehow needs it.

Comment: yes i tried,but that time it is giving entirly different output.